# How do I launch an app inside of my flutter app?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to build a flutter app that could launch all kinds of apps with a button. But I can't find a way to launch an app without using a browser or going through the google play store and the app store.

Is there a way to launch the app directly without using a browser or the play/app store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try my plugin [flutter_appavailability](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_appavailability): A Flutter plugin that allows you to check if an app is installed/enabled, launch an app and get the list of installed apps.
Methods available:

- checkAvailability(String uri)
- getInstalledApps() (only for **Android**). Unfortunately, for iOS there is no way to get the list of installed apps!
- isAppEnabled(String uri) (only for **Android**)
- launchApp(String uri)

In the README.md file there is an example with screenshots